# How can I efficiently model the sum of Bernoullli random variables?

Tags: perl, statistics, simulation, montecarlo

I am using Perl to model a random variable (`Y`) which is the sum of some ~15-40k independent Bernoulli random variables (`X_i`), each with a different success probability (`p_i`). Formally, `Y=Sum{X_i}` where `Pr(X_i=1)=p_i` and `Pr(X_i=0)=1-p_i`.

I am interested in quickly answering queries such as `Pr(Y<=k)` (where `k` is given).

Currently, I use random simulations to answer such queries. I randomly draw each `X_i` according to its `p_i`, then sum all `X_i` values to get `Y'`. I repeat this process a few thousand times and return the fraction of times `Pr(Y'<=k)`.

Obviously, this is not totally accurate, although accuracy greatly increases as the number of simulations I use increases.

Can you think of a reasonable way to get the exact probability?

Comment: Interesting question, but for the _exact_ probability you need to either find the formula in a statistics book or derive it yourself using calculus.  In other words, this is not really a programming question.  On the other hand, when you do find a formula that purports to give the answer, you'll want to make sure the formula is consistent with the best simulation you've been able to program.

Comment: With so many variables, it should be safe to use a gaussian approximation. Unless you have pathological cases (such as a lot of p_i=0) and need extremely high accuracy.

Comment: @Giacomo Verticale: `p_i`s are usually very small. In some cases a Poissonian is much better than a Gaussian.

Answer (score 3):

First, I would avoid using the `rand` built-in for this purpose which is too dependent on the underlying C library implementation to be reliable (see, for example, my [blog post](http://blog.nu42.com/2010/09/be-vary-of-using-built-in-rng-for.html) pointing out that the range of `rand` on Windows has cardinality 32,768).

To use the Monte-Carlo approach, I would start with a known good random generator, such as [Rand::MersenneTwister](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Rand::MersenneTwister) or just use one of [Random.org](http://www.random.org/)'s services and pre-compute a CDF for `Y` assuming `Y` is pretty stable. If each `Y` is only used once, pre-computing the CDF is obviously pointless.

To quote [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution):

> In probability theory and statistics, the ***Poisson binomial distribution*** is the discrete probability distribution of a sum of independent Bernoulli trials.
>
> In other words, it is the probability distribution of the number of successes in a sequence of *n* independent yes/no experiments with success probabilities *p1, …, pn*. (emphasis mine)

[Closed-Form Expression for the Poisson-Binomial Probability Density Function](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/Xplore/login.jsp?url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fiel5%2F7%2F5461631%2F05461658.pdf%3Farnumber%3D5461658&authDecision=-203) might be of interest. The article is behind a paywall:

> and we discuss several of its advantages regarding computing speed and implementation and in simplifying analysis, with examples of the latter including the computation of moments and the development of new trigonometric identities for the binomial coefficient and the binomial cumulative distribution function (cdf).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I recall, shouldn't this end up asymptotically as a normal distribution? See also this newsgroup thread: http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Sci/sci.stat.consult/2008-05/msg00146.html

If so, you can use [Statistics::Distrib::Normal](http://home.online.no/~pjacklam/perl/modules/html/lib/Statistics/Distrib/Normal.html).

Comment: DISCLAIMER: I'm definitely not an expert on the topic and would strongly suggest you wait for an answer from one (Sinan definitely is)

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the exact solution you can exploit the fact that [the probability distribution of the sum of two or more independent random variables is the convolution of their individual distributions.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_convolutions_of_probability_distributions) [Convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Discrete_convolution) is a bit expensive but must be calculated only if the `p_i` change.

Once you have the probability distribution, you can easily obtain the CDF by calculating the cumulative sum of the probabilities.